# How to find private key on build.secondstate

Tags: dapp-development, private-key

I'm a beginner in ethereum application developing. Actually I started some days ago with a book and now I tried to build my first smart contract using BUIDL, actually at this site: https://buidl.secondstate.io/.
I send 0.10$ to my default address, just to try to "deploy to the blockchain" setting provider, gas, and so on. It works. But what happens if I quit of that session?? I still have eth on my default wallet, I know that I can import it on another build instance, but how can I find the private key??

[image]

For example I want to import the Default account of the following image, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Pratically, buidl.secondstate addresses and theirs keys are stored in cache! Thus click F12, go to Application tab and search in Local Storage -> https://build.secondstate.io click it and it will show an hashmap to the right with key "build" and "value" a lot of charactertics, including each address and private key.